# saveAll() not adding belongsTo key to model

Tags: cakephp, model

I have 2 models, Guest and Asset. Asset belongsTo Guest. On submission, I use saveAll() to a) create the guest table entry and b) asset information. This works well, but I need to add the Guest.id to the Asset.guest_id (which I was under the impression gets done automatically when I use saveAll().

Any advice?

```
 // Asset model belongsTo:
     public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array('className' => 'User'),
    'AssetType' => array('className' => 'AssetType'),
    'Status' => array('className' => 'Status'),
    'Guest' => array('className' => 'Guest')
);

 // Controller:
 public function index() {
        pr($this->request->data);
        if($this->request->is("post")) {
            if($this->Asset->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("A new asset has been loaded");
            }
        }
        $assetTypes = $this->Asset->AssetType->find('list');
        $this->set("assetTypes", $assetTypes);
    }
```

Comment: what is your `$this->request->data` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears that I had a hasOne and belongsTo both in my Asset model.

I removed that hasOne and only had the belongsTo setup, and it works!